# Find the only path javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path-finding

I need help in trying to solve this coding challenge:

Giving an array of strings that represent the name of the island, n the number of queries, starting island, ending island.

Taking into consideration that there is ONLY one path that leads from starting island to ending island.
Input Format:

- The first line contains the count of connections n.
- The second line, contains two islands name seprated by a space. The first is where Mario is right now and the second one is where Mario wants to go.
- n lines follow, each containing two islands name(A and B) separated by a space . Each line indicate a connection between the island A and the island B

This is a sample to understand better the challenge:

```
input sample: 
5// number of queries

yoshi donut // frist string is the starting island,second is the end

// this our table.
donut vanilla
donut twin
twin forest
choclate donut
forest yoshi

output sample:
forest twin donut

Explanation 
There are 5 connections, and Mario is currently at yoshi island, his hometown is donut island. So the path is forest -> twin -> donut 
Notice how the start island is not printed but the final island is.


function getMarioHome(n,pos,dest, arr) {

var arr = [{a:"donut",b:"vanilla"},{a:"donut",b:"twin"},{a:"twin",b:"forest"},{a:"choclate",b:"donut"},{a:"forest",b:"yoshi"}];


var uniqueArray = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.a === pos || item.b === pos;
}) // meaning that you created a temp table holding all possible connections from destination

console.log(uniqueArray);
}
```

I am stuck here for the past 24H!.

Comment: How is the table represented actually ? Is it a flat array or array of arrays or an array of objects ?

Comment: no mention of the array type here. I have updated the question to include the input format. @rach8garg.

Comment: If I were you I would try to create a recursive function goes trough all the connections connected to the current island(like you found your uniqueArray method). When you have the connections you can call the recursive function from the connected island. when calling the function again include the path that was added. When the function finally reaches the the island return the path. when the function reaches a point where there are no more connected islands to explore return false. if the recursive function returns a path then return that path.

Comment: @frithjof I will try and look into that and post the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to delete this file from my computer:) I hope you found your own solution.

This is not the fastest solution since it will try to find every possible route. To improve performance it should stop looking for routes when a valid route is found. This could however be used to find the route with the least hops.

```js
var arr = [{a:"donut",b:"vanilla"},{a:"donut",b:"twin"},{a:"twin",b:"forest"},{a:"choclate",b:"donut"},{a:"forest",b:"yoshi"}];

function gotoIsland(targetIsland, currentIsland, path) {
  path = path || []; // initialize path if not set
  if(targetIsland == currentIsland) {
    return path;
  }

  
  let connectedIslands = arr.filter(pair => pair.a == currentIsland || pair.b == currentIsland) // get pairs that are connected to current island 
  .map(pair => pair.a == currentIsland ? pair.b : pair.a) // get the connected islands name

  var possiblePaths = connectedIslands.map(nextIsland => {
    var hasTravelevedToIsland = path.filter(previousIsland => previousIsland == nextIsland);
    // if they have not been to the island go to the island
    if (hasTravelevedToIsland.length == 0) {
      // copy path so the path is not corrupted during branching paths
      var copyPath = path.slice();
      copyPath.push(nextIsland);
      return gotoIsland(targetIsland, nextIsland, copyPath);
    }
    return false
  }).filter((path) => path != false)
  if (possiblePaths.length) {
    if (possiblePaths.length == 1) {
      // if there is only a single path then flatten the array
      return possiblePaths[0];
    } else {
      // allow support for multiple paths :D
      // problem with this is that the output can wary depending on how many paths there are
      // if you only want 1 solution then just return the first element.
      return possiblePaths
    }
  } 
  
  // return false if there is no way to get to the island from the current island
  return false;
}

var path = gotoIsland("donut", "yoshi");
console.log("solution", path);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, this is the possible solution based on the insights from @frithjof:

1/ extract all the connections from destination.

2/ make a recursive function that goes through each connection

```
2-1/ if(destination is reached){
     return true; console.log(the result)
}
2-2/ if(not the destination && ,no more path){
   return false;
}
2-3/ else {
   return path;
 }
```

NB: this is not tested yet in JS.

Comment: Let me know when you solve it. Then we can compare solutions.